# Can you add an if/get/echo statement in a shortcode

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

For some time now I been creating custom shortcodes to help display various information on my Wordpress site, without having to creat custom page / post templates and it's been working great.

I have also recently been implementing the Advanced Custom Fields plugin as well, versus hoe I was originally adding meta-boxes to custom post types and it has improved how I develop the site.

When creating custom post template, I can use something like this to display information:

```
<?php if(get_field('email_address'))
{ echo '<a href="mailto://' .get_field('email_address') . '">EMAIL</a></div>'; }
?>
```

Basically, if it has information it will display otherwise, do nothing. Where I have my question and can not figure out, is there a way to have an if / get statement in add_shortcode details?

Below is a shortcode, which lists a directory church locations and it's details, but in some cases they will not have all of the information. It's easy when it's just plain text like a physical address, as if nothing is available - nothing is display as the  wrapping that part of the text has no CSS like padding.

Where I run into a problem is things like the email or website. Even if they do not provide either of these, the coding still displays the text "Email" or "Website", but obviously no link. Ideally - this text would not be display at all.

So it possible to have an if / get type of statement with the add_shortcode coding to make this happen?

Here is the coding I am currently using.. Thanks in advance for any assistance and advice..

```
add_shortcode( 'directory' , 'Directory' );

function Directory($atts) {

$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'category' => ''
), $atts );

$categories  = explode(',' , $atts['category']);

$args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'church-directory',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'orderby'         => 'title',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'tax_query'     => array( array(
                            'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                            'field'     => 'term_id',
                            'operator' => 'AND',
                            'terms'     => $categories
                        ) )
    );

    $string = '';
    $string .= '<div style="margin-top: -30px;">';
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
        return false;
    }

    while( $query->have_posts() ){
        $query->the_post();
        $string .= '<div id="directoryWrapper">';
        $string .= '<div><h1><a style="text-transform: uppercase;" href="' .get_field('custom_url') . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h1></div>';
        $string .= '<div>' .get_field('address') . '</div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
        $string .= '<div>' .get_field('phone_number') . '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        $string .= '<a href="mailto://' .get_field('email_address') . '">EMAIL</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        $string .= '<a href="' .get_field('custom_url') . '">WEBSITE</a></div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
        $string .= '</div>';
    }

    $string .= '</div>';
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $string;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.. here is the final code in case it helps someone wanting to do something similar:

```
    add_shortcode('directory', 'Directory');
    function directory($atts){

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'category' => ''
), $atts );

    $categories  = explode(',' , $atts['category']);

$args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'directory',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'orderby'         => 'title',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'tax_query'     => array( array(
                            'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                            'field'     => 'term_id',
                            'operator' => 'AND',
                            'terms'     => $categories
                        ) )
    );

ob_start();

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    ?>
        <?php
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>


        <div id="directoryWrapper">
        <h1><a style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 600;" href="' .get_field('custom_url') . '"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php if(get_field('address')) { echo '' . get_field('address') . ''; } ?>
        <?php if(get_field('phone_number')) { echo '<br>' . get_field('phone_number') . '&nbsp;'; } ?>
        <?php if(get_field('email_address')) { echo '<a href="mailto://' .get_field('email_address') . '">EMAIL</a>&nbsp;'; } ?>
        <?php if(get_field('custom_url')) { echo '<a href="' .get_field('custom_url') . '">WEBSITE</a>'; } ?>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>


        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php 
}
wp_reset_query();//reset the global variable related to post loop
$retVal = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

return $retVal;
    }
```